# Tracking view count with Google Analytics Custom Var

Tags: google-analytics

I've added a custom variable to my site to try and track when pieces of content are viewed. However it doesn't seem to be tracking properly. The code looks like this:

```
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',1,'contentView','42',3]);
```

And is set just before trackPageView like so (Account removed):

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-0000000-0']);
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'domain.com']);
_gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',1,'contentView','42',3]);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
```

Now the page this code is being displayed on was viewed 275 times yesterday (I can tell by searching with the URL). But the custom var only appears under "Custom > Custom Variables" 15 times, under the heading "visit starts".

Presumably this means something like visits started (landed) on that page 15 times, but I don't really care about that. I want to know how many times that piece of content was viewed altogether.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default reports for custom variables don't make much sense when you're dealing with custom vars on the page scope (scope 3).

You should create a custom report to see that custom Var with Pageviews and Unique Pageviews as metrics. Than you would see the data you're expecting.